Replicating an Encrypted Database to a Non-Encrypted Target
Using transactional replication, can an encrypted database (TDE encryption) be replicated to a non-encrypted target without issue?

Yes.  This is part of the "transparentness" of TDE.

TDE and replication
Replication doesn't automatically replicate data from a TDE-enabled database in an encrypted form. Separately
enable TDE if you want to protect distribution and subscriber
databases.
Snapshot replication can store data in unencrypted intermediate files
like BCP files. The initial data distribution for transactional and
merge replication can too. During such replication, you can enable
encryption to protect the communication channel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16#tde-and-replication
